Django: How to solve multi-dev issue for database that should be populated
I'm working on a project with some people and we've been adding images and some text to the database (Postgres) through the django admin, they get added to the database but when someone commits to the GitHub repository and someone else pulls and runs he doesn't see any of the things added to the database. It looks like django doesn't leave instructions of what to populate to the database in the code itself so how can we get around this issue? Is there a standard method people already use?

Are different users using the same database connection as the original?

The standard way to populate a development DB is with fixtures.
If your DB is populated, you can dump files into a fixture file with:
django-admin dumpdata my_model > myapp/fixtures/my_model.json

To populate an empty DB from fixture files, use:
django-admin loaddata my_model

